# Update time field in MySQL DB from Java

Tags: java, mysql, time

I need to Update the MySQL DB from Java. In particular, I need to update the time field called as ´t_field´.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TimeTest` (
  `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_field` TIME NOT NULL,
  `resQty` INT(3)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How can I use the symbol `"` in the String to write the UPDATE statement if JAVA?

```
String query = "UPDATE TimeTest SET t_field = "00:05" WHERE id=1"; // sure, it does not work
```

Comment: have you tried using backslash before " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use single quotation

```
String query = "UPDATE TimeTest SET t_field = '00:05' WHERE id=1";
```

or

```
String query = "UPDATE TimeTest SET t_field = \"00:05\" WHERE id=1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid relying on the external representation of the time used by your database, which could vary depending on the database, locale and settings. Instead, use a prepared statement:

```
String query = "update TimeTest set t_field = ? where id = 1";
PreparedStatement stmt = cnx.prepareStatement(query);
Time time = Time.valueOf("00:05:00");
stmt.setTime(1, time);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

This might look like a detail for times, but when you'll have to do it with dates or timestamps, it will become much more important.

Answer (score 1):

Used `\"`

```
String query = "UPDATE TimeTest SET t_field = \"00:05\" WHERE id=1";
```